# How to manipulate SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, csv

I have the following code which reads each line and takes each column value in the line and adds it to a list array:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(textBox1.Text))
                    {
                        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
                        while (!parser.EndOfData)
                        {
                            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                            foreach (string field in fields)
                            {
                                colArray.Add(field);
                                colArray.ToArray();
                                MessageBox.Show(field);
                            }
                            MessageBox.Show(colArray.Count + "");
                            colArray.Clear();
                        }
                    }
}
```

I already have the table created with the column name.

How would I insert each column data until the end of row for the table has been reached and start all over again?

P.s. the first line is the header, How would I skip that line and start from line #2?

Comment: Skip: `var i = 0; foreach(...){i++;if (i==1) continue; ...}`

Comment: What do you mean by start all over again? Are yo trying to parse/import multiple files?

Comment: To skip, if you have can be `using System.Linq;` then you can employ that like so: `foreach(line in lines.Skip(1)) { ... }`

Comment: lines.Skip(1) didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you've supplied it appears that you really want to structure a whole row that will be inserted into the database.  The underlying SQL might look like this:

```
insert into MyTable values ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

While the input file looked like this:

```
header 1, header 2, header 3
a, b, c
```

In order to accomplish that you would assemble that statement, or that database call, after you've closed your while loop; that's when the row is complete and ready for insertion.

Also, just a note, your `colArray.ToArray()` isn't really doing anything without assigning the result to a variable.

**Update:**

You've asked about dynamic columns as well and your code is already on that path.  You've also suggested that the row of data in the CSV was already escaped by quotation marks?  If that is the case then we're getting no benefit from the `TextFieldParser` and I have removed it from the answer below:

```
foreach(string line in lines.Skip(1))
{
    var sqlfmt = "insert into mytable values ({0})";
    var insert = string.Format(sqlfmt, line);
    // todo: somedb.execute_sqlcommand(insert); or something
}
```

**Notes:**

1. I think you'll really really want to quote and escape and sanitize your inserts to protect yourself from sql injection.
2. You could also read the column names from that first row.

Comment: I want to take into consideration I don't know how many columns is in the row. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Well you're already on that path by iterating over the columns.  At each completion of a `line in lines` that's the end of a row.  You can also assemble the columns this way.  I'll update the answer in a moment.

Comment: That `lines.Skip(1)` is still displaying the first row when I add a MessageBox for debugging purposes. Also, as per your code, remove the WHILE loop and remove anything that's not with the above code?

Comment: Is that header row also in `textBox1.Text` then?  Your code suggests that you're already reading all the lines into, literally, `lines` variable.

Comment: The header row is in the file which is specified in the textbox1 field, yes

Comment: Answer updated again.  Now using the text parser on only the current line.  All you need to do now is get textBox1's text into "lines" and the rest looks good.

Comment: I will test it out with the updated code. I will update you once I am done. Thanks so much.

Comment: This is what I have so far: http://ideone.com/LqHS3G (The table is created dynamically and I changed my code to match yours but I am receiving the following error in `asy.ExecuteNonQuery()`: `Incorrect syntax near 'Type'.

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'U'.

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'U'.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55391/discussion-between-searchforknowledge-and-jeffdot).

Comment: I see what is happening, somewhere the quotation is being taken out while saving causing my query to crash :/

Comment: Thanks for the update. Would I be able to skip the first row now?